# syncdb error using mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

(i m using python2.7.6 on django 1.6)

I've created an app call signups with django, when i used sqlite i had no problem to do python manage.py syncdb but now that i m using mysql i get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/firstweb/signups/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class SignUp(models.Model):
  File "/var/www/firstweb/signups/models.py", line 7, in SignUp
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255, null=True, blank=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 685, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'
```

this is my app in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

# Create your models here.

class SignUp(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255, null=True, blank=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255, null=True, blank=True)
        email = models.EmailField()
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return smart_unicode(self.email)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have a typo: use 'max_length' instead of 'max_lenght':

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return smart_unicode(self.email)
```